# MySQL - how to update in batches of rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table `eurusd_tickdata_2017` with 21704041 rows.

Now I want to calculate the average of forex_askprice and forex_bidprice for each row and update to forex_midprice. I tried using `update eurusd_tickdata_2017 set forex_midprice=(forex_askprice+forex_bidprice)/2`, but it met error for MySQL connection lost. I thought this is because of too many rows to update. So, I want to run the update in batches of rows. But don't know how to do this.

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Storing calculated data in a simple field is usually not such a good idea. Consider using a view or generated columns to calculate the midprice field.

Comment: Does your table have a primary key?  If so, what is it?  Do you need to do this once or on an ongoing basis?

Comment: The primary key is 'pk_eurusd'. I need to do this once.